# Plotting line segments in complex plane

Tags: plotting, complex

Recent versions of Mathematica have introduced various functions for plotting in terms of complex numbers and complex functions, including `ComplexPlot`, `ComplexListPlot`, `ComplexRegionPlot`, and `ComplexVectorPlot`. These functions allow direct use of complex numbers and complex functions without the user having to explicitly apply `ReIm` or otherwise split complex objects into their real and imaginary parts.

**Question:** Is there a built-in function that provides some very basic and essential plotting functionality for geometric objects specified in terms of complex numbers. For example:

- plotting a line segment in the complex plane by directly specifying its endpoints as complex numbers?
- plotting a circle (not a filled disk!) in the complex plane by specifying its center directly as a complex number and its radius?

(And if not, why on earth not?? Given that Mathematica regards complex numbers as being so fundamental that one must explicitly override assumptions of numbers being complex when you want them to be real, it seems surprising to me that it's taken even this long for Mathematica to build in the complex plotting functions I cite.)

As a very basic and simple example, I want to do make the following kind of graphics — *without* having to use `ReIm` to split up explicitly all the complex numbers into their real and complex parts.

```
Graphics[{Circle[ReIm[2 + 2 I], 1], PointSize[Large], Red, 
  Point[ReIm[2 + 2 I]], Thick, Blue, Line[ReIm[{1 + 2 I, 3 + 2 I}]]}, 
 Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> ReIm[0]]
```

[image]

At least `ComplexListPlot` would allow plotting one element there, namely, the center of the circle, and that could be combined using a `Show` with the other graphics. Still, that leaves the circle and line segment to treat.

Answer (score 3):

**Update 2:** We can simply wrap the first argument of `Graphics` with a function that `Replace`s `Complex[a, b]` with `{a,b}`:

```
ClearAll[foo]
foo = Replace[#, Complex[a_, b_] :> {a, b}, All] &;

SeedRandom[77]
rc = RandomComplex[1 + I, 6] ;

Graphics[foo @ 
  {Thick, {RandomColor[], Circle[#, RandomReal[{1/10, 1/2}]]} & /@ rc, 
   Blue, Dashed, Line[Partition[rc, 2, 1]],
   PointSize[Large], Gray, Point@rc, 
   Red, BSplineCurve @ rc, 
   Opacity[.3, Purple], Rectangle[rc[[1]], rc[[-1]]],
   Opacity[.3, Green], Polygon[RandomSample[rc, 4]]}]
```

[image]

**Update:** We can define primitives with complex coordinates:

```
ClearAll[complexCircle, complexLine, complexPoint]

complexCircle[cntr_Complex, r_] := Circle[ReIm @ cntr, r]
complexPoint[c_Complex] := Point[ReIm @ c]
complexPoint[c:{__Complex}] := complexPoint /@ c
complexLine[{a_Complex, b_Complex}] := Line[ReIm[{a, b}]]
complexLine[l:{{_Complex, _Complex}..}] := complexLine /@  l
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[77]
rc = RandomComplex[1 + I, 5] ;
Graphics[{Thick, { RandomColor[], complexCircle[#, RandomReal[{1, 5}]]} & /@ rc,
  Blue, Dashed, complexLine[Partition[rc, 2, 1]], 
  PointSize[Large], Gray, complexPoint @ rc}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
{pnt1, pnt2, pnt3} = {1 + 2 I, 3 + 2 I, 2 + 2 I}
```

You can use a [`ComplexContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexContourPlot.html) and [`ComplexListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexListPlot.html) and combine the outputs using `Show`:

```
Show[ComplexContourPlot[Abs[z - pnt3] == 1, {z, 3}] , 
 ComplexListPlot[{{pnt1, pnt2}, {pnt3}}, Joined -> {True, False}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Blue],  Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]}], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: That does the trick. I use the word "trick" advisedly: Surely there should be a simpler, direct way to plot geometric objects in the complex plane. In other words, although the answer gives the graphics result I want, it involves "jumping through hoops." After all, for ordinary graphics using Euclidean coordinates, one simply uses `Circle` and `Line`. Surely there should be a `ComplexCircle` and `ComplexLine`. One could define a function `ComplexCirclePlot` to provide the expression you gave for the circle, but that is already an actual plot rather than a graphics primitive.

Comment: @murray, please see the update.

Comment: Yes, those functions in your update take care of things. I still want them, and more, to be built into Mathematica. Perhaps if you contributed them to the Wolfram Function Repository, we'd have a start in getting WRI to take action. (Note: In all this, I'm trying to wean myself from the complex graphics capabilities of David Park's *Presentations* addon, since he no longer maintains it.)

Comment: The argument patterns in the suggested functions don't suffice to handle arguments such as in `complexLine[{2 + 2 I, 2 + 2 I + 1/Sqrt[2] + 1/Sqrt[2] I}]`, even if in the definition, the appearances of the variables on the right-hand sides are wrapped in `N`. Any ideas?

Comment: wrapping the input list with `N` works: `complexLine[N@{2 + 2 I, 2 + 2 I + 1/Sqrt[2] + 1/Sqrt[2] I}]`

Comment: Having to wrap the actual argument to `complexLine` in `N` is awkward. I really need a way so that an inexperienced user could just plug in the desired complex numbers and have the function "just work".

Comment: Update 2 seems to fail, as does Update, for things like a line from `0` to `Sin[1+I]`.

Comment: Per Bill's comment at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/230292/148, the pattern test should be simply `_?NumericQ`. Then to mimic the behavior of the build-in `Arrow`, the definition should be: `ComplexArrow[l : {__?NumericQ}] := Arrow[ReIm[l]]`. And similarly for `ComplexLine`.

Comment: complexCircle[I,1] works as expected, but complexCircle[0,1] does not recognize 0 as a valid complex number, nor does it recognize any real number as being (also) complex.

Answer (score 0):

Very helpful example, thanks.

I just added in some matching coloring of the points and circles, since I'm always forgetting how to do this and need practice. ;-)

Since usually all the complex numbers are at the top level, maybe we can almost always get by with just putting the replacement rule at the end of the Graphics section.

```
SeedRandom[1]
p = RandomComplex[1 + I, 6];
clrs = Table[Hue[0.8 (i - 1)/5], {i, 1, 6}];

Graphics[
  {
   Thick,
   Table[{clrs[[i]], Circle[p[[i]], RandomReal[{0.1, 0.5}]]}, {i, 1, 
     6}],
   Thin,
   Blue, Dashed, Line[p],
   AbsolutePointSize[12], Point[p, VertexColors -> clrs],
   Red, BSplineCurve @ p,
   Opacity[0.3, Purple], Rectangle[p[[1]], p[[-1]]],
   Opacity[0.3, Green], Polygon[RandomSample[p, 6]]
   }
  ] /. Complex[a_, b_] :> {a, b}
```

[image]