# Head of complex sum

Tags: functions, complex, argument-patterns

We have:

```
     1 + 2 I + 3 + 4 I // Head
Complex
```

and

```
     1 + 2 I + 3/5 + 4/5 I // Head
Complex
```

But we get:

```
     1 + 2 I + 3/Sqrt[5] + 4/Sqrt[5] I // Head
Plus


     1 + 2 I + 3/Surd[5, 2] + 4/Surd[5, 2] I // Head
Plus
```

**Questions:**

1. Why is this happening?
2. What can be done so that the latter two complex expressions in fact result in a `Complex` head?

**Purpose:** I'm trying to use functions defined in the form

```
func[{a_Complex, b_Complex}]:= ...
```

where they are to be used with arguments built up from complex numbers, e.g.,

```
func[{1+2I, 1 + 2 I + 3/Sqrt[5] + 4/Sqrt[5] I}]
```

**Edit:**  Start, for example, with:

```
complexArrow[{a_Complex, b_Complex}] := Arrow[ReIm[{a, b}]]
```

which will not work for the kind of argument shown above, built up from complex numbers. Even if this is modified to...

```
complexArrow[{a_Complex, b_Complex}] := Arrow[ReIm[{N[a], N[b]}]]
```

...still the following does not work:

```
complexArrow[{2 + 2 I, 2 + 2 I + 1/Sqrt[2] + 1/Sqrt[2] I}]
```

*Note:* I'm trying to define a function for complex arrows analogous to those suggested in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/230280/148. The same problem already arises with `complexLine`, among the other functions, proffered there.

Comment: @Bill: I thought using `N` would helps, but not so far. See my edit to the question.

Comment: @Bill: Yes, `N` works there. But I'd like a robust function even an inexperienced user could apply, without the fuss of knowing you have to insert an `N` wrapper sometimes in the actual argument; I'm hoping, somehow, that this can be taken care of in the function definition, by the way it handles the formal argument.

Comment: @Bill: Yes, using the `_?NumericQ` pattern that works just fine! But to mimic the behavior of the built-in `Arrow`, I think the definition should be `ComplexArrow[l : {__?NumericQ}] := Arrow[ReIm[l]]`.